# UWP Template find and modify control

Tags: c#, templates, uwp, tabview

I have a TabView whose header and item use template. I have found the elements in the header template, but when I change their visibility programmatically, the properties still remain the same. Why is that? How should I fix it?

I have tried changing text NameTextBlock and NameTextBox to strings like "hello" "world" but it's still showing the original text.

```
    private void RenameClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var flyoutItem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
        var tab = (TabViewItem)PlaylistTabView.ContainerFromItem(flyoutItem.DataContext);
        var header = tab.HeaderTemplate.LoadContent();
        RenameHeader(header, true, true);
    }

    private void RenameHeader(DependencyObject header, bool isEdit, bool selectAll)
    {
        var NameTextBlock = (TextBlock)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(header, 1);
        NameTextBlock.Visibility = isEdit ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        TextBox NameTextBox = (TextBox)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(header, 2);
        NameTextBox.Visibility = isEdit ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        if (selectAll) NameTextBox.SelectAll();
    }
```

---Update---

This is my HeaderTemplate:

```
        <controls:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Playlist">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Audio" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="NameTextBlock"
                        Margin="10,0,5,0"
                        Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBox
                        x:Name="NameTextBox"
                        Margin="10,0,5,0"
                        AcceptsReturn="True"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        ManipulationCompleted="NameTextBox_ManipulationCompleted"
                        Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I recommend using bindings to solve your problem.

You can try to have the class inherit the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and call the `OnPropertyChanged` method when the property changes.

```cs
public class Playlist:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then you can bind it in the `HeaderTemplate`.

```xml
<controls:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Playlist">
        <TextBlock Text={x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay} />
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:TabView.ItemHeaderTemplate>
```

Similarly, if you need to change the visibility of the `TextBlock`, there are two ways.

The first is to add the `Visibility` property to the Playlist class, which is created in the same way as the `Name` property.

The second is to convert through `IValueConverter` according to a certain condition (such as `IsEdit`).

Best regards.

Comment: I get your idea. I also have attached my HeaderTemplate code. Do you know why the programatical way is not working?

Comment: The `LoadContent` method will create a new UIElement based on the DataTemplate. So the header you get is not the header you are currently seeing.

Comment: Can I change elements in the `Template` programmatically? I need to dynamically change something.

Comment: You can add an `IsSelected` property to your Playlist model, modify its value when `SelectionChanged`, and change the display of the ItemHeaderTemplate by binding. It is not recommended to use `VisualTreeHelper` to get the template content directly. This will reduce the software performance due to the reflection.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear. What I want to achieve is that, I want to change the AlbumCover(an Image who gets source from Thumbnail asynchronously by randomly picking a local music file in my `Playlist` model) when its `TabItem` is selected, and I also need to change the background accordingly in an async way. Do you still think it is proper to use binding?

Comment: Do you need to set up such a Cover for each DataTemplate? If so, then I recommend reading the image before data binding and setting an attribute (such as Cover) for the image and displaying it when the item is clicked. Or create such a Cover property for the Model in advance, bind it first, and assign it to it when needed. But it's best not to click on the control and then assign a value to the control. If you feel that your problem is not well explained, please open a new question and do not ask under the old question.

Comment: Sorry for asking under the old question again and again. But I still think my solution should have a better performance unless VisualTreeHelper takes seconds to change the content. So it's still the old question, how can I modify the Template programmatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't recommend using `VisualTreeHelper`. If you really want to use `ViusalTreeHelper` to find elements, check out the related [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) to find a solution. But believe me, what `VisualTreeHelper` can do, Binding can do it, and the performance is better.